# DateTimePicker does not generate valuechanged when today clicked

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

I am developing in Visual Studio 2015 and have created a WinForm application targeting .NET Framework 4.5.2.

I have placed a DateTimePicker control on a form.  I have code on the ValueChanged event handler.

I have put a a breakpoint on the first line of code in the ValueChanged event handler.

When I run the application in the debugger and press the "today" button in the datetimepicker, it fills in todays date, but the ValueChanged event is not triggered.   If I click the dropdown arrow that brings up the calendar and select a date, it Will trigger a ValueChanged event.

Not sure if the element I click on is called the "today" button.  It is just left of the drop down arrow and when clicked fills todays date into the datetimepicker.

I need to capture when the user clicks this and run some code.

Would appreciate and ideas on how to capture this as it does not trigger a ValueChanged event.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot with the "today button" marked visually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that because the Date time picker initializes with Today's date/time, when you just hit the drop down, it isn't changing it, it still has today's date/time. If you re-select today's date, the time component of the datetime has changed, triggering the valueChanged event.

There is a dropDown event that might be of use to you: [DropDown Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.dropdown(v=vs.110).aspx). It triggers when the Calendar is shown.

Another event might be the [MouseUp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseup(v=vs.110).aspx) event, you'd have to use where the "Today" button is located to capture that click.

[Here's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker_events(v=vs.110).aspx) the MSDN link of the different events available to a DTP.

Comment: Not just "possible".  [The specs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value(v=vs.110).aspx) say that's exactly what happens in their Remarks.

Comment: OK.  This answer led me to understand a bit more.   The datetimepicker must display empty when the datetime value is DateTIme.MinValue.  To accomplish this, I use mydatetimepicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom and then mydatetimepicker.CustomFormat = "    "  so when I click on the drop down it just shows todays date which it is already loaded with.  If I click the drop down arrow it triggers the event.   Sorry for the wasted bandwidth.

Comment: No problem. Events can get a bit tricky or fiddly. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I recommand that you expect that the user has choose the current date. I mean that you should set your default value to current date. And in the ValueChanged event, you do exactly what you need to do when the user change date.